# Show the following function is well defined

Tags: calculus, measure-theory, fubini-tonelli-theorems

Consider the sequence $f_n(x)=e^{-nx}-2e^{-2nx}$ for $x>0$

a)Show $f(x):=\sum^\infty_{n=1}f_n(x)$ is well defined for $x>0$ and determine $f$

b) Show $$\sum^\infty \int_{(0,\infty)}f_n(x)\neq \int_{(0,\infty)}\sum^\infty f_n(x)$$

I dont even know how to attack this question,
For part (a) it seems like if I have $x\neq y$ and $x,y>0$ the function is trivially well defined but I dont know what does the question mean by determine the function.
for part (b) I was thinking about using Fubini's theorem and use the fact that we can see the sum as integrating with respect to the counting measure, let $\mu$ be counting measure on $(\mathbb{N},\scr{P}(\mathbb{N}),\mu)$ then we have $$\sum^\infty \int_{(0,\infty)}f_n(x)=\int_\mathbb{N}\int_{(0,\infty)}f(n,x)dxd\mu$$
and $$ \int_{(0,\infty)}\sum^\infty f_n(x)=\int_{(0,\infty)}\int_\mathbb{N}f(n,x)d\mu dx$$
And since $\mu$ is not sigma finite we must not have the above two equal.

Can someone give me some idea on how to get started ? thanks

Comment: For a you need to show that the sum converges for any $x \gt 0$.  That gets you well defined.  To find $f$ you are expected to sum the geometric series and get a relatively simple expression.  You should say why you are allowed to rearrange the series to use the geometric series sum formula.  For b just compute both sides using your $f$ on the right.  They should disagree.

Comment: @RossMillikan Thanks, I see for convergence since $r=\frac{1}{e^x}<1$ for all $x>0$ and hence we must it to be convergent. And everything else is just computation. Cant believe I spent my whole afternoon on this.